# Serving a NodeJS app via apache

Tags: node.js, apache, server

I am running a nodejs application on my apache2 web server. On trying to access the domain page `example.com` it shows the default apache page instead of the apps page. But on going to `example.com:8090` it show the node application

This is the config

```
<VirtualHost *80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyVia Full

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    <Location />
        ProxyPass http://serverip:8090
        ProxyPassReverse http://serverip:8090
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work, just know it's not ideologically the most elegant solution.

```
# Main site proxy
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAlias www.example.com
     ServerName example.com
     ProxyPreserveHost On

     <Proxy *>
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
     </Proxy>
     ProxyPass / http://nodejsIP:8090/
     ProxyPassReverse / http://nodejsIP:8090/
</VirtualHost>



     # Subdomain proxies
     <VirtualHost *:80>
         ServerAlias www.api.example.com
         ServerName api.example.com
         ProxyPreserveHost On

         <Proxy *>
             Order allow,deny
             Allow from all
         </Proxy>
         ProxyPass / http://nodejsIP:8090/api/
         ProxyPassReverse / http://nodejsIP:8090/api/
     </VirtualHost>
     <VirtualHost *:80>
         ServerAlias www.apps.example.com
         ServerName apps.example.com
         ProxyPreserveHost On

         <Proxy *>
             Order allow,deny
             Allow from all
         </Proxy>
         ProxyPass / http://nodejsIP:8090/apps/
         ProxyPassReverse / http://nodejsIP:8090/apps/
     </VirtualHost>
```

Note: if your apache server and node server are both running off the same box and hence have the same IP, use http://localhost for the **nodejsIP**